# How to a override parent theme page that has been included with require_once?

Tags: functions

I need to override a parent theme file which is added in function.php like this:

```
if (class_exists('Woocommerce')) {
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/woocommerce/config.php');
}
```

A template override does not work. If I add config.php into the child theme here: mychild/woocommerce/config.php has no effect.

I can get my own config.php file to run from the child theme folder like this:

```
if (class_exists('Woocommerce')) {
include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/config.php');
}
```

But I get all kinds of 'Cannot redeclare' errors, so clearly this is not an override, but just stacking the same file.

I have read everything I can find on this and am having no luck.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Actually there is a filter you can add `template_directory` to make `get_template_directory()` return path as for `get_stylesheet_directory()` BUT make sure the filter is applied only when needed (i.e overwriting config.php file)..

Comment: Are there any resources that guide you how to do this?